# MS SQL server casting without exception

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, exception

Is there any "convert" function in MS SQL server that allows to cast types safely(without throwing exception). I need something like "tryParse" in C# lang but as SQL statement.

More detailed, I need the following statement returns zero or any else but throwing exception.

*select convert(float,  'fjsdhf')*

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 36):

This will default non-numerics to 0 and will not require another statement:

```
 SELECT CASE 
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(myvarcharcolumn)=1 THEN 
       CONVERT(float, REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(myvarcharcolumn)), ',', '.')) 
    ELSE 0 END AS myfloatcolumn
```

The REPLACE() function call is used to change commas to periods. Commas are used in some cultures as a decimal separator (e.g., "1,25" instead of "1.25"), but unless your server is set up with one of those as the default culture, ISNUMERIC() will return 1 but CONVERT() will throw an error. This *does* mean that your strings should not use commas as thousands separators, but in most cases, a comma for a decimal placeholder is more likely to be a decimal placeholder.

The LTRIM(RTRIM()) call is because ISNUMERIC() will return 1 for a string with leading or trailing spaces, but CONVERT() can't deal with them. So, you must trim your strings.

The only remaining potential issue is that ISNUMERIC() will return 1 if the number can be represented as an int, currency, decimal, or float, but you're only converting to a float. Realistically, a float can store just about anything you throw at it, but if you were trying to convert to an int instead, ISNUMERIC() would return 1 for a value like "2.5", but CONVERT(int, '2.5') will still throw an error.

Comment: In SQL Server 2008 R2 `IsNumeric` returns 0 or 1 and not a boolean. So you need `WHEN ISNUMERIC(myvarcharcolumn) = 1`

Comment: It is a good method, but still gives an error if the column only contains `-`.

Comment: Also gives error on unkown symbols that print as squares.

Answer (score 14):

In SQL SERVER 2012 there are new functions to deal with this

try_cast
try_convert
try_parse

Comment: For those who to lazy to google, here is the link to this answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 :) And if it fails it returns NULL which you can handle easy with ISNULL, COALESCE, ...

Answer (score 9):

You can test that a value is numeric with the TSQL function ISNUMERIC()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx

And, in case you aren't already aware of it, TSQL now has a TRY CATCH construct.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296.aspx

Comment: TRY CATCH is not fit into my solution as I'm limited and can't add extra statements. I consider to add extra function that will do casting safely. Something like, "myconvert(type, data, default value)", I wonder if there is another way that would free me from add custom function into database.

Comment: "SELECT CASE" in the below answer is better and more flexible than TRY...CATCH.

Answer (score 3):

If the version of SQL you are using supports the CLR you can write TryParse style methods.\
It doesn't meet your criteria of adding custom functions to the db though.  But it's probably going to be faster than a SQL UDF.

something like

```
[SqlFunction]
public static SqlDouble TryParseDouble(SqlString str)
{
  Double d;
  bool success = Double.TryParse(str, out d);
  if (!success)
    return SqlDouble.Null;
  return new SqlDouble(d);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @SoMe1 FLOAT = 100.99;

DECLARE @SoMe2 VARCHAR(10) = 'TEXT HERE';

SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, @SoMe1) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @SoMe1 END
AS Rslt;      -- Output will be 100.99

SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, @SoMe2) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @SoMe2 END
AS Rslt;      -- Output will be 0
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, considering this question is almost 6 years old: In [SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) you can use `TRY_CONVERT` which will return NULL on error; which is probably precisely what you want.