# How to "TryCast" data in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Table1 has data to be imported into Table2.  Table1 contains only varchar fields, but they will be cast to the type of whatever field they are going to be imported into in Table2.

The data has to be imported one row at a time, so I can catch exceptions to find out which rows cause a problem but this doesn't tell me which column is the culprit and if there are very many exceptions than it's slower than just checking for valid data ahead of time (not to mention I want the ability to fix problems before starting the import process anyway... preferably without having to actually do a transaction and roll it back just to find out what the issues are).

Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```
select RowNumber from table where cast(fieldName as SomeDataType) = 0
```

Obviously that statement doesn't make sense because this is not what cast does, but the idea is that I'd like a function that tries to cast the data and returns a true or false value depending on whether the cast was successful.

Is there some easy way to do this that I've overlooked?

Comment: Just to clarify, there *is* a column called RowNumber so I'm not asking about that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related posts:

[MS SQL server casting without exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042816/ms-sql-server-casting-without-exception)

[How do I TryParse in SQL 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225211/how-do-i-tryparse-in-sql-2000)

You may end up needing to write a user-defined function to that combines a few different methodologies to attempt the cast. Since it's an import, I'm assuming that performance isn't the highest concern; calling a UDF *will* slow down the process.

You could also try writing a CLR stored procedure and use .NET type checking and conversion to at least broadly categorize your data (exact classification may be difficult due to the differences in types between .NET and T-SQL).

Comment: Yeah, my first inclination was to see if the destination datatype was a date or numeric type and use IsNumeric/IsDate to look for invalid data in the source column as I think that would probably be sufficient for my app.  But it just seemed like there should be a built in way to do this in sql.  Sounds like there's prolly not though.

Comment: As for speed though, it does need to be fairly snappy for data up to 20k-ish rows.  The idea is that the user selects the file to import and a datagrid below pulls up any exception rows for them to edit before they do the import.

Comment: @Brandon Moore - Why not parse the data file in memory for basic validation errors before even trying to insert the records? That way, you can avoid accessing the database (unless you need to look up values for additional validation) and present a rich, structured return value to the user. This should reduce the amount of time spent inside the database which may reduce table locking during a lengthy import process.

Comment: Locking isn't an issue.  There won't be any other connections open when this gets done.  So I am using code to send a query per each column in the source data to look for invalid data based on the destination data type.  I could do it the way you suggest too but I assumed it would be faster to let sql do the looking (haven't bench marked it, but so far performance is sufficient).  I was just hoping for a generic statement I could use for all types instead of having to check what type it is and change the statement based on that type.

Comment: Not really the answer I was hoping for, but it looks like a better answer probably doesn't exist so I'll give it to ya :)