# How to verify that whether a column is an encryption key/value or plain text in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to verify that whether a column is an encryption key/value or plain text in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Do you have access to the table?  Can you query it?  Are you looking for a general solution that can go out and find all encrypted columns?  Little more detail would be nice.

Comment: maybe duplicate from this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958511/determining-whether-a-column-is-an-encryption-key-or-plain-text

Comment: Is the encryption done in sql server or the application? Your question simply does not have anywhere near enough information for anybody to be able to answer it. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx

Comment: Hi Guys,Thanks for taking initiation on this point.The sample code shown below CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY EncryptTableKey
WITH ALGORITHM = TRIPLE_DES ENCRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert
 
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY EncryptTableKey DECRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert 
 
UPDATE encryption_key
SET PasswordKeyEnCol= ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('EncryptTableKey'),PasswordHash),SaltKeyEnCol = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('EncryptTableKey'),  Now in same another store proc i want to verify that whather the column PasswordKeyEnCol has encrypted value like if condition and some other stuff

Answer (score 0):

Cell or column level encryption in SQL Server 2008 is an external operation - meaning SQL Server doesn't actually know it is encrypted. You create the key, read plaintext data in original type, encrypt and write cipher text as varbinary type back to the table. That means if you complete the process, you'll have a new column of varbinary type.

There are no catalog views you can query since as far as SQL Server is concerned, it is just another varbinary column. There are ways to figure it out manually by checking the length and/or type of the column if the original type is not varbinary. You might also check actual values or use regular expressions if you want to verify per row instead of the entire column. If the original type is varbinary, this is probably not the best place to design a solution.